# How to merge my commits one by one in Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

Now I have several commits and one commit has been +2 in Gerrit, I want to merge it, but don't know how to achieve it.

I work in a scrum team and the master requires us do not combine multiple commits to one, so must merge one by one

my commits is like this:
Commit 6
Commit 5
Commit 4
Commit 3
Commit 2
Commit 1

the commit 2 has been +2 in the commit, I want to merge it, how can I do this?

Comment: If commit 2 depends on commit 1, it doesn't make sense to merge it until commit 1 has merged. If there isn't a real dependency, you can rebase commit 2 on the target branch so that it doesn't have any unmerged dependencies.

Comment: Hi, in fact they have dependency. Now I let the reviewer +2 follows the commit time line, Would you please tell me how to merge the all commit? thanks.